# Load table with angular dropdown 4

Tags: angular, dropdown

I need to load a table with a dropdown that is loaded with information obtained from a post, but when choosing a dropdown option I need to send certain parameters to send to a post and return information to me and load the table

Comment: help me..!! please

Comment: show me your code where you want to send parameters and fetch detail from the post request, also show code where you want to load data ?

Answer (score 1):

**Overview of the solution**

**Component**

```
  myValue:number;
  tableData:any;
  selectedValue:number;

  select(value : number){
    // you get the selected value from the drop down
    Make a Http call to service here like 
    getMyTable(value).subscribe(data => this.tableData = data); // passing value as parameter

  }
```

**Template**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (change)="select($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let value of values " value= {{value.id}}>{{value.name}}</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf = "tableData"> // this will load data when your table data has value else will not be shown
  // table data
</div>
```

Hope this is what you want